# Select2 template does not autocomplete when tagging

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-select2, jquery-select2-4

I'm trying to use Select2.js version 4.0 to create tag selections. I would like a new tag to be created if it doesn't exit, and I would like the results formatted using a `'data-html'` tag.

The problem is that the two elements(`createTag` and `templateResult`) work independently, but when I use them together the autocomplete options no longer show up when an user types in the search box.

Am I doing something wrong, or is this a limitation of Select2?

**application.js**

```
  $("#taglist").select2({
    tokenSeparators: [',', ' '],
    tags: true,
    createTag: function (tag) {
        // Case insensitive search for tag
        tagExists = false;
        $("#taglist option").each(function() {
            if ($.trim(tag.term).toUpperCase() == $.trim($(this).text()).toUpperCase()) {
                tagExists = true;
            }
        });

        // If the tag does not exist create it
       if (!tagExists) {
             return {
                id: tag.term,
                text: tag.term + " (create)",
                isNew: true
            };
        }
    },
    templateResult: function (choice) {
      if (!choice.id) { return choice.text; }
      var $choice = $(
        '<span><a>' + data.element.getAttribute('data-html') + '</a></span>' 
      );
      return $choice;
    }
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no `data.element` when tagging, so your templating methods need to be able to handle that. Ideally, your methods should be able to work with `data.text` and anything else would be optional.

So you should be falling back to `data.text` if there is nothing in the `data-html` attribute on the element.